how to put a background image for an android button
I would like to have an android button with an image and not a background color but I can't do it I always have the default color when I compile or even in the android studio view.
I would like to have an android button with an image and not a background color so I tried to put the path to my image directly:
with : android:background="@drawable/button"
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="124dp"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:textColor="#05F192"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

but when I compile or put the view on android studio there is always the pink color by default. I also tried to create an xml file that points to my image :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</selector>


but nothing changes, there is still the default color

Use ImageButton or AppCompatImageButton. They have an attribute: android:src to set an image/icon
